# CodeIgniter on subdomain (mod_rewrite issue)

Tags: apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, apache2

Can someone tell me how can I have mod_rewrite working on subdomain? The htaccess code here http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html is only working on normal folders, not subdomains.

Why is that and how can I get it working?

Thanks.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more? what is happening, what is expected? etc; Folders are folders, subdomains are just a way to access a 'folder'

Comment: Have you set your base URL in application/config/config.php file?

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your server. We had CI set up on a staging.[domain].com sub-domain for one of our clients and our .htaccess mod-rewrites worked fine. But, if you could explain a bit more about what you're experiencing perhaps a better answer could be provided.

Comment: Check your virtual host for the subdomain, if you're using apache make sure you set AllowOverride All, instead of AllowOverride none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this problem too.  On certain hosts, this works:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Notice that I simply removed the slash from in front of the index.php on line 3.

Another solution is to add RewriteBase to the block, as such:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /path/to/app
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Finally, if you get 500 errors from these, you may try this technique, which works on most servers I've tried: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Dreamhost_.htaccess/